# Linking library in python

Tags: python, c++

I want to use the Cantera library in python. I have been using it for C++ and I am linking my adding these couple lines to my makefile:

```
CANT_LIB = $HOME/usr/local/Cantera201/lib/
CANT_INC = $HOME/usr/local/Cantera201/include/ -I $HOME/usr/local/Cantera201/include/cantera \
```

with `CANT_LIB` and `CANT_INC` being called when compiling.

I have very limited experience with python. Is there an equivalent to linking libraries in python? I have tried adding the cantera path to `PYTHONPATH` but it did not work. I am working on a Linux server on which I do not have access to super user and `python 2.6.6`.

Comment: Check this out : http://effbot.org/zone/import-confusion.htm

Answer (score 0):

You need to install Cantera's Python module to use it, the raw C/C++ libraries aren't enough. If you install using [the directions on their website](http://www.cantera.org/docs/sphinx/html/install.html) it should be installed to the appropriate Python `site-packages` directory automatically, and [available for use with just `import cantera`](http://www.cantera.org/docs/sphinx/html/cython/migrating.html#importing-the-python-module).